# Process Forking with PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, pcntl

I have copied the below code and on running the code it always shows

> parent

as output.But the source file says it will display output as

> child
>
> parent

.Please advice me "How to implement threading in PHP".

```
<?php
 if (! function_exists('pcntl_fork')) die('PCNTL functions not available on this PHP installation');
 $pid = pcntl_fork();
 if($pid) {
   echo "parent\n";
 }
 else {
   echo "child\n";
 }
?>
```

Note:While running in cli getting an error

> PHP Warning:  Module 'pcntl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Source:http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/php/process-forking/

Comment: Are you sure `pcntl_fork` is available? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Yes.There is no error messages.

Comment: Please try this line: `if (! function_exists('pcntl_fork')) die('PCNTL functions not available on this PHP installation');` to cheack if pcntl is available.

Comment: Is this a verbatim copy? Because the comments after the `else` are wrong.

Comment: @S.Visser I have added that.still it shows "parent"

Comment: Could you block before the end (right before `?>`) and see in `top` or `ps` that it did, in fact, fork?

Comment: Also, what is the actual value of `$pid` after the call? The example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) has a little more extensive example.

Comment: Also, on that documentation page: "It is not possible to use the function 'pcntl_fork' when PHP is used as Apache module. You can only use pcntl_fork in CGI mode or from command-line." But you say there are no errors ....

Comment: @BartFriederichs I got an error "PHP Warning:  Module 'pcntl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0" while running in terminal